# Route::controller() alternative in Laravel 5.3+

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

I just upgraded from Laravel 5.2 to 5.3. I am using [Laravel-DataTables](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/) package for several tables in my application.

After upgrade when I run `artisan serve` I'm receiving:

```
[BadMethodCallException]
Method controller does not exist.
```

I've tracked the issue down to this piece of code in my `routes.php` (now `web.php`)

```
Route::controller('datatables', 'ProfileController', [
    'anyOrders'  => 'datatables.dataOrders',
    'anyProperties' => 'datatables.dataProperties',
]);
```

This is the suggested way to route the queries for [DataTables Documentation](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/starter#register-routes).

Was the `Route::controller()` deprecated, and what is the alternative to for these routes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The explicit `routes` will be:

```
Route::get('/datatables/orders', array('middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@anyOrders'))->name('datatables.dataOrders');
Route::get('/datatables/properties', array('middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@anyProperties'))->name('datatables.dataProperties');
```

Comment: thank you, solved the error. I had to remove `'middleware'=>'auth'` though.

Comment: @ArturGrigio happy to help

Comment: ok, so I know implicit routes are gone in 5.3. Is there a package that still enables this somewhere? Or what can I do to bring this back? - without discussing why I shouldn't do it... :)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue as you, and none of the alternatives (explicit declaration or publishing) was good enough. There were also some alternatives which required changing too much code.

This is why I wrote a class called AdvancedRoute, which serves as a drop in replacement.

It can be used by simply replacing Route::controller with AdvancedRoute::controller like this:

```
AdvancedRoute::controller('users','UserController');
```

Full information how to install and use find at the GitHub repo at:

https://github.com/lesichkovm/laravel-advanced-route

Hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 2):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0

> The following features are deprecated in 5.2 and will be removed in the 5.3 release in June 2016:
>
> - Implicit controller routes using `Route::controller` have been deprecated. Please use explicit route registration in your routes file. This will likely be extracted into a package.

Comment: missed that one :( thanks a lot :)  What is the *explicit route* for my use case?

Comment: @ArturGrigio "Please use explicit route registration in your routes file."

Answer (score -1):

You can use resource().

```
Route::resource('users','UserController');
```

Note: the "get" prefix is not needed. `getIndex()` = `index()`